# BackgroundTransferRequest response header

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm creating a POST request with the BackgroundTransferRequest and the server return me a response. In this response there is a header (ETAG) witch I need to access to.

How I can access to response headers on the BackgroundTransferRquests objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundTransferRequest doesn't provide any response object, and I there's no way of getting the data you're interested in. As a workaround, after your file is uploaded, you could ask your web service explicitly about that file, via WebRequest object. Or get rid of that BackgroundTransferRequest and use WebRequest for everything.